# What is Cloud Computing and Cloud Hosting

Tags: cloud-hosting

I try to know about cloud computing but could not understand and kindly also make clear that how cloud hosting is different with simple shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Cloud Computing is a term that refers to the practice of using a network of remote servers hosted on the Internet to store, manage, and process data, rather than a local server...

For details you can refer to this website :http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-cloud-computing.html

Difference between Cloud Computing and Simple shared hosting :  Cloud Computing is a hardware in a data center shared by many users whereas typical web hosting gives you a single portion of a server or a fixed server.

For in-depth information, please refer : http://www.qrimp.com/blog/blog.The-difference-between-Web-Hosting-and-Cloud-Computing.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

-- > Cloud computing :

In science, cloud computing is a synonym for distributed computing over a network, and means the ability to run a program or application on many connected computers at the same time.

The term "cloud computing" is mostly used to sell hosted services in the sense of application service provisioning that run client server software at a remote location.

Cloud use service model : IaaS (Infrastructure as a service) , PaaS(Platform as a service) , SaaS (Software as a service ).

Simple example that use cloud is : Microsoft Azure , Amazon's Ec2 , google drive

Cloud is only application that provide user infrastructure , platform or software online with user-defined requirement and is scalable . that is maintained and upgraded by cloud provider.

user have to pay only for what they are using.

-- > Cloud Hosting :

Cloud hosting sites basically operate across various web servers that are interconnected, and as opposed to traditional hosting forms such as shared hosting, and dedicated hosting, data is rendered from various servers.

[simple meaning is cloud service provider host the cloud for user to use like storage of data , run web application online or use any kind of software through internet which is located on server of service provider ]

You pay for what you use: As your business needs fluctuate, you've nothing to worry as you can change your hosting packages based upon your needs, and pay only for what you use.